# What is the best way to work with text macros in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create something like a textbox control in which I should be able to insert macros. These macros will be replaced by real values at a later time. The user should be able to select these macros from a list and the value will be inserted after the cursor.

For example:

This is your message ***\current_date\***.

Where current_date is a macro and maybe is colored in another foreground color.

The user should still be able to edit the text box, but the macro should be treated as a whole. ( When you press backspace or delete, the whole macro should be deleted).

How can I create this control?

Comment: This can get complex - you need to consider what should happen if the cursor is inside the macro when delete/bs pressed - if it is a valid macro & cursor inside it what happens if cut or paste is performed. What if macro partially selected & del/bs pressed or cut/paste performed? If you can address these issues then Behaviors can be very useful in adding functionality.

Comment: I don.t need copy-paste, nor macro editing :) just the macros to.be treated as whole

Comment: You may not need it - but most text boxes support it - so you need to handle it is what I am getting at. It was one of the things that caught me out - I had handled typing & deleting to ensure correctly formatted text only to find the correct formatting could be invalidated by cut & paste operations.